# How to create file with n integers between -1000 and 1000 python?

Tags: python, file

My program should verify that n is a positive integer. If it isn't it should return string "Enter a positive integer."  If n is positive, it should create a file with the name given which contains n integers between -1000 and 1000 (random). I think this is how you open the file but I'm clueless and have no idea what to do next.

```
    import random
    def createFile(myFile,n):
         myFile="fileName"
         outFile=open(myFile,"w")

         if n<0:
             return "Enter a positive integer."
```

Comment: do you mean random numbers between -1000 and 1000 ?

Comment: I don't think you should return a string from this function... Also, have you tried using the [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) module?

Comment: `myFile="fileName"` overwrites filename which you use with `createFile("some_filename")`

Comment: Are you sure this is what you want to do?  This is a rather poor design for a function.  Among other things, when **n** > 0, how does the file pointer get back to the calling function?  Even if that's the return value, it's not particularly useful to have the function return either a string or a file handle.

Answer (score 3):

Use `random.sample` to extract n values from a `range`. Wrap that in a list comprehension to convert integers to strings, adding newlines, and pass that to the `writelines` method.

```
import random
def createFile(myFile,n):

     with open(myFile,"w") as outFile:
        outFile.writelines(["{}\n".format(x) for x in random.sample(range(-1000,1001),n)])

createFile("foo.txt",45)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok... The first thing would be playing with [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) (in Python3) or `raw_input` (in Python2) to ask the user for a number. I suggest you give it a try to this, typing a few negative numbers and a then a possitive number. You can even try to type something that can't be converted to `int` to see the exceptions happening:

```
number = -1
while number < 0:
    number_string = input("Enter a possitive number. ")
    number = int(number_string)
print("Yay! Got a positive number: %s" % number)
```

(that snippet is for Python3, in Python2, you should substitute `input` by `raw_input`)

Once you get your positive number in the `number` variable, you can use it to iterate, creating (and writing) a new entry in your file:

```
with open("./stack_046.txt", "w") as f:
    while number > 0:
        random_generated = random.randint(-1000, 1000)
        f.write(str(random_generated))
        f.write("\n")
        number -= 1
```

If you don't want to use the special keyword `with` (which you should, and it's very worth it that you investigate [what it does](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm)) you could always do:

```
outFile = open("./stack_046.txt", "w")
while number > 0:
    random_generated = random.randint(-1000, 1000)
    outFile.write(str(random_generated))
    outFile.write("\n")
    number -= 1
outFile.close()
```